# Como desabilitar o evento de 'click' nos dias do "Date Range Picker"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, data, click

Estou tentando impedir o evento "click" em cada dia do [DateRangePicker](http://www.daterangepicker.com/), apenas estou tentando impedir que os usuários alterem o período.

Eu criei um *pen* no Codepen, segue link: https://codepen.io/jnts/pen/yQPwmB

**HTML**

```
<input data-start="16/11/2018" data-end="16/12/2018" type="text" name="dates">
```

**Javascript**

```
const self = $('input[name="dates"]')

self.daterangepicker({
    applyButtonClasses: 'd-none',
    showDropdowns: false,
    opens: "center",
    drops: "down",
    autoApply: false,
    startDate: self.data('start'),
    endDate: self.data('end'),
    minDate: self.data('start'),
    maxDate: self.data('end'),
    locale: {
      format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
      separator: " - ",
      firstDay: 1
    }
});
```

Eu já tentei adicionar o atributo "*disabled*" no `input`, mas isso apenas impede o evento 'click' no `input`, logo, o DateRangePicker nem mesmo aparece.

Eu só quero mostrar o período em um modo '**somente leitura**'.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: nOlá, pesquisando aqui, o `DataeRangerPicer` não tem opção 'readonly'. Aproveitando que você ja esta utilizando o jquey, tente utilizar o Datepicker do mesmo, ja utilizei e sei que existem maneiras de implementar o seu cenário, abaixo vou listar alguns links que podem lhe ajduar: - Documentação Jquey datepicker: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ - Como deixar o Jquery datepicker read-only: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7812063/jquery-datepicker-readonly Vale a pena dar uma olhada nesse ultimo link, pois o cenário é bem parecido com o teu! Espero ter ajudado, abraços!